# How to change the folder view default to list view in Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

I want to make the settings in Windows Vista such that every folder I Open should have list view by default. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you set detail view for the current folder in Explorer, navigate to **Tools -> Folder options**, and select "Apply to all folders".

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work on my computer.